# Show that this holomorphic function can be extended to $D_{2}((0,0) ;(2,2))$

Tags: several-complex-variables

consider a domain in $C^{2}$:$\Omega=D_{2}((0,0) ;(1,2)) \cup\left\{(z, w) \in \mathbb{C}^{2}:|z|<2 \text { and } 1<|w|<2\right\}$ and $f \in \operatorname{Hol}(\Omega)$, I want to show that f can be extended to $D_{2}((0,0) ;(2,2))$
and I also want to show that $\Omega$ is not a domain of holomorphy， I want to use Cauchy integral formula to formulate the extension but I don't know how to do it, could you please help me? thank you